# Ошибка: ORA-06550. Как объявить локальную переменную, как присвоить значение переменной, как вставить переменную в условие предикат?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DECLARE
    L_DATE_1 DATE :='2018-09-01';
    L_DATE_2 DATE :='2018-11-12';
    begin
    SELECT C."APPCM_PHOTO_CASE_MATERIAL_ID" ID,
           C.APPFE_EVENT_ID ev_id 
    FROM table_1 C
WHERE C.t_appcm_violation_date between L_DATE_1 and L_DATE_2
```

> ошибка Error report -
>   ORA-06550: Строка 5, столбец 1:
>   PLS-00428: в этом предложении SELECT ожидается фраза INTO

Что хочет от меня, если я уже идентифицировал переменную?

---

```
    with period as (
        select
            to_date('2018-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd') L_DATE_1,
            to_date('2018-11-12','yyyy-mm-dd') L_DATE_2
        from
            dual
    )
 SELECT C.APPCM_PHOTO_CASE_MATERIAL_ID ID,
        C.APPFE_EVENT_ID ev_id 
 FROM period,table_1 C
 WHERE C.t_appcm_violation_date between L_DATE_1 and L_DATE_2
```

***Вот, так я получил желаемое без ошибок. Как сделать аналогию через объявление локальной переменой ?***

Comment: Почему у вас блок FROM пустой? Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: PL/SQL не позволяет делать выборку (SELECT) на экран, поэтому он ожидает предикат INTO, чтобы присвоить возвращаемые значения переменной(ым)

Comment: Будет проще если вы объясните что вы пытаетесь сделать, вместо того чтобы решать эту проблему (Это похоже на [«Ошибку молотка» или «Ошибку XY»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy))

Comment: Kromster.Добрый день. Этот кусок кода вырезка, в from подзапрос, так как я думал для примера будет достаточно.

Comment: Переменные объявлены, значения присвоины и вставлены в предикат where. А в чём собственно вопрос?

Comment: Oxdb, выскакивает ошибка, поскольку ждёт оператора INTO, непонятно почему когда значение присвоил, есть другие примеры передачи значения переменной ?

Comment: В блоке PL/SQL результаты `select` должны быть чему-то присвоены. Сейчас Вы выбираете `C.APPFE_EVENT_ID` в «пустоту», что и приводит к ошибке. Объясните, для чего Вы написали этот запрос и что собираетесь делать с его результатом, чтобы Вам можно было помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PLS-00428: в этом предложении SELECT ожидается фраза INTO

Сообщение об ошибке однозначно указывает, что надо объявить локальную переменную для результата и добавить её в запрос: `SELECT ... INTO local_result FROM ...`.

Но в вопросе запрос явно вернёт не одну строку, поэтому тут нужен курсор и цикл.
Лучше неявный курсор, который неявно объявит переменную для результата в теле цикла.
Как-то так:

```
DECLARE
    L_DATE_1 DATE :='2018-09-01';
    L_DATE_2 DATE :='2018-11-12';
BEGIN
    for rec in (
        SELECT 
           C."APPCM_PHOTO_CASE_MATERIAL_ID" ID, C.APPFE_EVENT_ID ev_id
        FROM table_1 C
        WHERE C.t_appcm_violation_date between L_DATE_1 and L_DATE_2
        ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('fetched row:'||rec.id||','||rec.ev_id);
    end loop; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

если вам просто нужно вывести на экран результат параметризированного запроса, то для задания переменных в SQLPLUS можно воспользоваться коммандой SQLPLUS: `DEFINE`:

```
DEFINE L_DATE_1 = to_date('2018-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
DEFINE L_DATE_2 = to_date('2018-11-12','yyyy-mm-dd')

SELECT C.APPCM_PHOTO_CASE_MATERIAL_ID ID,
        C.APPFE_EVENT_ID ev_id 
FROM period,table_1 C
WHERE C.t_appcm_violation_date between &L_DATE_1. and &L_DATE_2.
```

**В чём разница между `DECLARE` и `DEFINE`:**

- `DECLARE` - предикат в PL/SQL, применяемый в анонимных SQL блоках.
- `DEFINE` - нечто схожее с коммандами препроцессора в `C`/`C++`. `DEFINE` будет работать только в программе-клиенте (`SQLPLUS`, `SQL Developer`, `SQLcl`, etc). Программа-клиент заменит все вхождения таких "переменных" на их значения **перед** тем как послать запрос на сервер. Т.е. Oracle DB  получит запрос с уже подставленными значениями.

Comment: "будет работать только в SQLPLUS" - не только, в SQL Dev., SQLcl, например, тоже.

Comment: @0xdb, да, неудачно сформулировал. Сейчас попробую улучшить формулировку...